# How to set up property for testcontainers

Tags: java, testcontainers

I want to set up ryuk.container.image as a private registry image. What I tried:

- -Dryuk.container.image
- -DRYUK_CONTAINER_IMAGE
- -DTESTCONTAINER_RYUK_CONTAINER_IMAGE

Without success.

When I create custom testcontainers.properties and add: ryuk.container.image=ryuk.image:3.0.3 it being picked up, but when I inject maven property there It does not substitute it:

ryuk.container.image=${my.property} - not working

How I can specify ryuk.container.image as -D command or substitute it with maven property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_CONTAINER_IMAGE=testcontainers/ryuk:0.4.0` as an environment variable. `-D` it allows to define a system property which is not taken into account.

Read more [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#configuration-locations).